# Displaying z-indexed divs side by side

Tags: jquery, css

I have a container div and a button with following markup and css

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <table class="tbl">
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
  </table>
</div>

<button id="btnAdd" type="button">Add</button>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
  position:releative;
  background-color:#d0d0d0;
  widht:90%;
  height:50px;
}
.innerdiv
{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  background-color: #D57657;    
}
.tbl{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.tbl td
{
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
```

I am using jQuery to dynamically add child divs to the container div

```
$(function(){
  $("#btnAdd").click(function(){
      $(".container").append("<div class='innerdiv'>I am new</div>");
  });
});
```

The problem is all the divs that I create by clicking button hide each other and I want these child divs to be displayed side by side. How can I accomplish this.
You may want to have a look at it as [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZedBee/JpKaz/)

**Edit** The initial issue was solved by removing `position:absolute` from `.innerdiv` once there are no elements in the `container` div. I have a table inside my container div and suggested solutions add the child divs below the `table` which I actually wanted to display over the `table' rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `position: absolute` for your divs, juse float them to the left and they will be side by side, otherwise you need to calculate position (top, left)

```
float: left;
```

Comment: sorry .. missed `position:absoulute` part. Nice its fixed :)

Comment: But you see, if container div contain some other elements, it does affect where the children appear. Plz see the updated code and jsfiddle

Comment: All I want the created children to appear over the top row or may be bottom row based on some condition in script

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely positioned div's have their final rendering position, regardless of other div's or html elements. In other words, absolutely positioned elements do not break the natural layout of normal html elements.

So either you have to manually keep position x,y variables and increase them with each div appended, or make them float and just add them.

Comment: did you also remove "position:absolute" ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope  this: http://jsfiddle.net/EDpQw/ is what you need

```
.innerdiv
{
  z-index:1;
  background-color: #D57657;
  float: left;
}
```